# Spanish word for Seoulite?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, préstamo-lingüístico

I wonder if there is a Spanish word for Seoulite, a citizen of Seoul, the capital of South Korea.

Seoulite is an English demonym and French has a similar word Séoulite, but I couldn't find a corresponding word in Spanish.

- Cambridge dictionary EN --> ES for Seoulite: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english-spanish/?q=Seoulite
- Collins dictionary EN --> ES for Seoulite: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english-spanish?q=Seoulite

If there is no such a word, what would be a good choice when the general rule of word formation in Spanish is applied?

Answer (score 2):

## Seulense / seulés

> Ambos nombres designan a los habitantes de Seúl. En español se han usado tradicionalmente los gentilicios seulés y seulense para nombrar a las personas originarias de Seúl, capital de Corea del Sur.

<sub>*Both names designate the inhabitants of Seoul. In Spanish, the demonyms seulés and seulense have traditionally been used to name people from Seoul, the capital of South Korea.*</sub>

<sub>*Source: [FundeuRAE](https://www.fundeu.es/dudas/palabra-clave/gentilicios/#:%7E:text=seulense%20y%20seul%C3%A9s,capital%20de%20Corea%20del%20Sur.)*</sub>